# Log4j encoding problem

Tags: java, logging, encoding, smtp, log4j

I configured log4j SMTPAppender to send emails to me on errors. It works, but I have problem with non ASCII data. Configuration uses [HTMLLayout](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/HTMLLayout.html) and their documentation states:

> Appenders using this layout should have their encoding set to UTF-8 or UTF-16, otherwise events containing non ASCII characters could result in corrupted log files.

My log files must contains UTF-8 data, but I can't find where I can set encoding for appender. Here is appender configuration:

```
<appender name="MAIL" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender">
    <param name="BufferSize" value="25" />
    <param name="SMTPHost" value="localhost" />
    <param name="From" value="myapp@...com" />
    <param name="Threshold" value="error" />
    <param name="To" value="me@gmail.com" />
    <param name="Subject" value="Error Occurred" />
    <param name="LocationInfo" value="true"/>
    <param name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <!--  <param name="Encoding" value="UTF-8"/> -->
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.HTMLLayout">
    </layout>
</appender>
```

When application runs I got:

> log4j:WARN No such property [encoding] in org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender

Comment: So based on your accepted answer, did you extend SMTPAppender? Care to give us the source?

Comment: Yes, of course: http://gist.github.com/252856

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [code of the latest SMTPAppender (1.2.15)](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4j/tags/v1_2_15/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/net/SMTPAppender.java?revision=572985), not only there no setEncoding, but the encoding does not even mentioned there.

Do you actually see issues with it? If so, why not inheriting from SMTPAppender or provide your own implementation?

Comment: Thank you, I have thought about it, but I hoped there are standart solution.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at logback? Its [SMTPAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SMTPAppender) supports setting the character encoding.

Answer (score 1):

The latest (1.2.16) version solves this.

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4j/tags/v1_2_16/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/net/SMTPAppender.java?revision=929374&view=markup

```
subject: line 144
body: line 390
content type: line 394
```

It's also mentioned in the changelog http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/changes-report.html#a1.2.16

```
SMTPAppender does not properly encode subject or content containing non-ASCII characters. Fixes 44644.
```

Answer (score -1):

set this property in log4j configuration:
log4j.appender.MyAppender.Encoding=UTF-8

Comment: I did what version of log4j are you running?

Comment: it is not working for me too. I use latest log4j lib log4j-1.2.16.jar. How can I solve it?